# How can I isolate a monitor from the desktop on a Windows 11 23H2 system?

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-11-v23h2, sunshine

I have a gaming desktop currently running Windows 11 23H2. I have 2 physical monitors that are 1080P and a fake monitor made up of an EDID plug that emulates a 4K 60hz HDR display. The EDID plug is used as a headless display for the Sunshine streaming server.

The issue I am having is I want that EDID monitor to not show the desktop. I want it to be a standalone monitor that only is used by Sunshine.

I had read on multiple forums and other places on the Internet that Windows is supposed to have an option called "Remove display from desktop" when you look in the advanced settings of the display properties. However, when I look for this setting it is not where to be found.

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?